# Used '--no-links' this no operation as wrappers only creates links now

Tags: bash, rvm

I am trying to write an init.d bash script for starting unicorn on boot.

I'm following this: https://rvm.io/integration/init-d

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 bin]$ rvm alias create vagrant ruby-1.9.3@vagrant --create
Creating alias vagrant for ruby-1.9.3-p545@vagrant.

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 bin]$ rvm wrapper vagrant --no-links unicorn
Used '--no-links' this no operation as wrappers only creates links now.
```

What does the error mean?

> this no operation as wrappers only creates links now

Comment: Mentioned this post here. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2434

Answer (score 0):

this means you can stop using the second step, it's now part of normal flow when installing gems, it just happens automatically, no manual wrappers creation

Answer (score 0):

Since wrappers are generated automatically by RVM now, all you need to do to execute Unicorn (in your above example) with RVM, is call it like this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p545@vagrant/bundle exec unicorn
```

Where `/usr/local/rvm/` is the output of `$ echo $rvm_path`

You also need to make sure that `bundle` is installed in the gemset/appears in the wrapper (this is done automatically when you create a new gemset while using the current version of RVM).